# Reversing a LinkedList of LinkedLists of Char recursively

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Im trying to recursively reverse a list of lists of Character **in place**. Reversing the outer lists is easy enough, however, trying to reverse the inner lists has turned out to be a bit more difficult, since I can't use the same method.

While I'm able to recursively call my method -which has a list of lists of Character as a parameter- on the rest of the list (outer lists), I don't have a method which takes a list of Character as a parameter.

I tried to define a local method using a lambda expression, however, lambdas only accept Interfaces in their params.

I also thought of making this into a generic method which just has a ListItem as a param, I'm not sure my prof would accept this though. She almost explicitly said that we have to use these parameters. However, she didn't rule it out.

I'm wondering what I could do otherwise.

Please note that I am a beginner and my approach might be entirely wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
public static ListItem<ListItem<Character>> reverseListOfListsInPlaceRecursively(ListItem<ListItem<Character>> listOfLists) {...}
```

Comment: If the prof asks you to use that signature, you probably have to use that one. That doesn't stop you from creating another method with your own parameters to be called.

Comment: You could write another method with this signature `public static ListItem<Character> reverseListInPlaceRecursively(ListItem<Character> list) {...}`.